# How to prevent the right click context menu to pop up using Qt, QML, and compiling to webassembly

Tags: qt, webassembly

I have a Qt 6.5 based app that compiles to WebAssembly, and I run it inside a browser (Firefox and Chrome tested).

It loads fine, but using the right mouse button for navigation is annoying, as it constantly opens the browsers context menu.

I have to versions of the App, one is `QOpenGLWindow` based, the other QML based. Both open the context menu.

I have tried to accept all `QOpenGLWindow::mouse*Event`s, but to no avail. I believe that this should be possible, as it's also possible for JavaScript.